# How to update new hostname in a file using ansible?

Tags: regex, linux, ansible, hostname

I am using below code to replace old hostname with new one, it is working except for hostnames starting with numbers.(OLD_HOSTNAME and NEW_HOSTNAME are `vars`)

```
  tasks:
  - name: "Updating file"
    replace:
      name: /tmp/interfaces
      backup: yes
      regexp: '(\s+){{ OLD_HOSTNAME }}(\s+)'
      replace: '\1{{ NEW_HOSTNAME }}\2'
```

If I replace **\1** with **\g<1>**, the hostnames starting with numbers will also get placed. But as per the ansible [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/replace_module.html), `\1 is used ambiguously`, and `\g<1> used explicitly`.

Question: Will this change impact any other format of hostname?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking  ... or maybe you don't understand what `\1`,`\2` (or `\g<1>` and `\g<2>` , respectively) do?  How about some example data?

Comment: Yes, I am new to all these, I understand these are backreferences but didn't quite understand the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the explicit form will not affect other hostname formats.

The reason why you have a problem when `NEW_HOSTNAME` begins with a number is that the `replace` string would become something like `\123-server\2` if `NEW_HOSTNAME` was `23-server` and there is no backreference `\123`. Using the explicit form preserves your original intent. In my example, `replace` would become `\g<1>23-server\g<2>`.